# Permission denied when opening socket or using resolver

Tags: linux, networking, resolve, linux-from-scratch

I've set up an LFS system and I must have missed a step somewhere.  I can only resolve hostnames if I am root:

```
$ host 6thstreetradio.org
net.c:150: socket() failed: Permission denied
net.c:150: socket() failed: Permission denied
host: can't find either v4 or v6 networking
$ sudo host 6thstreetradio.org
Password: 
6thstreetradio.org has address 67.246.2.103
6thstreetradio.org mail is handled by 5 6thstreetradio.org.
```

!?  Am I missing a permission somewhere in the proc filesystem?  Something else?  Google searches is turning up nothing, but I'm probably searching for the wrong thing.  The code reference in net.c is failing on simple socket creation:

```
s = socket(domain, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set the flag "CONFIG_ANDROID_PARANOID_NETWORK"? You can check the details here : [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/252261/network-access-issues-after-upgrading-to-squeeze). If so, please try this:

```
groupadd -g 3003 aid_inet
usermod -G -a aid_inet $YOUR-USER
```

Also please check the permission of binary files and the config files.

Comment: I think you got it: 
$ sch-i405_kernel>grep PARANOID .config
CONFIG_ANDROID_PARANOID_NETWORK=y
# CONFIG_MMC_PARANOID_SD_INIT is not set

Comment: The usermod thing didn't work, but that's not surprising since this is a linux subsystem running on android.  I'll try rebuilding the kernel and see if that works.

Comment: YAY!  CORRECTION: I forgot to do `newgrp aid_inet` as by user after adding the group.  It must be a magic name recognized by the kernel.  After doing that, the normal user as access to the network.  Checkmark applied.

Comment: @DavidDombrowsky Thumbs UP for you!  :)

Comment: I ran into almost the same problem with a Linux system on Android, although the group now seems to be called `android_inet` and I also had to make `/etc/resolv.conf` readable.